# How to get a string randomly in c++

Tags: c++

I'm making a program in which every time when I run the program, a random quotation is displayed. This should be done by using `rand` and `srand`. I'm making logic and searching but couldn't understand how to do it. Can someone please tell me what's wrong.

```
    const string Quot[14] = { "1)Love Pakistan", "2)Be Honest", "3)Work Work and Work", "4)I am always doing things I cannot do.That is how I get to do them.", "5)It is not what we take up, but what we give up, that makes us rich.", "6)You can do anything, but not everything.", "7)Thinking will not overcome fear but action will. ", "8)We read the world wrong and say that it deceives us.", "9)You miss 100 percent of the shots you never take.", "10)He is the happiest, be he king or peasant, who finds peace in his home.", "11)Your work is to discover your work and then, with all your heart, to give yourself to it.", "12)In order to be effective truth must penetrate like an arrow – and that is likely to hurt", "13)You must be the change you wish to see in the world", "14)Humans are satisfied with whatever looks good; ? Heaven probes for what is good." };
    for (int i = 0; i < 14; i++)
    {   
        int choiceLen[i] = c.getLenght(Quot[i]);
        const int randomLength = 1;
        string randomStr[randomLength + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < randomLength; i++)
        {
            randomStr[i] = Quot[i][rand() % choiceLen[i]];
            cout << randomStr[i] << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`rand` is a pseudo-random number generator. That means it isn't truly random, and one of the first limitations is that - for legacy reasons based in testability - it always starts with the same seed and thus always produces the same random sequence.

In order to break this, you need to provide some entropy, a random seed. The most common way to do this is to do the following at the start of main():

```
srand(time(nullptr));
```

Caveat: If you run this twice in the same second, it will get the same random seed.

If you have C++11 available to you, you can use `<random>` and `std::shuffle`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::array<std::string, 3> quotes = {
        "1 hello", "2 world", "3 hello world"
    };

    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 gen(rd());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<> quoteSeed(0, quotes.size() - 1);

    int quoteNo = quoteSeed(gen);
    auto quote = quotes[quoteNo];
    std::shuffle(quote.begin(), quote.end(), gen);
    std::cout << quote << "\n";
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/Lv1M7w

Comment: Just a side note: whether or not it is a good idea to always use the same seed depends on the use case. In scientific computing, it is often more important to have a number sequence that is as uncorrelated as possible, and for that some seeds give better results than others. In consequence, people often use "tried and true" seeds for this kind of use case.

Comment: what are seeds and this program is giving me these errors

Comment: Warning 1 warning C4244: 'argument' : conversion from 'time_t' to 'unsigned int', possible loss of data

Comment: Error 2 error C2057: expected constant expression                 Error 3 error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0 
    Error 4 error C2664: 'size_t strlen(const char *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'const std::string' to 'const char *'

Comment: Don't use `strlen` on a `std::string`, use `.length()`. e.g. `std::string x = "hello";` the length is `x.length()` not `strlen(x);`. If you are not familiar with basic usage of `std::string` I would suggest you read up on that before trying something more advanced.

Comment: To silence the warning about `time_t` to `unsigned int`, you can write `static_cast<unsigned int>(time(nullptr))` instead of `time(nullptr)`.

Comment: It also appears that your question doesn't entirely explain what you are trying to do - are you trying to select a random string from a list and then scramble the string and print the characters in a random order?

Comment: I've added a C++11 implementation of what it seems you were trying to do .

Comment: well,I was trying to just generate random string one by one whenever I run the program(not shuffle string).I'm studying OOP ,have not read about seed and shuffle but still trying my best.Thanks